# EnumWindowsProc как метод класса для EnumWindows?

Tags: c++

Как преобразовать это в члены класса, чтобы можно было присвоить полю g_HWND значение hwnd;

```
HWND g_HWND=NULL;
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProcMy(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD lpdwProcessId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&lpdwProcessId);
    if(lpdwProcessId==lParam)
    {
        g_HWND=hwnd;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProcMy,m_ProcessId);
```

Comment: так у вас и сделано в методе.... g_HWND=hwnd;

Comment: Я думаю, что Xie хочет сделать функцию EnumWindowsProcMy членом своего класса.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan если это был бы метод, то возникли бы проблемы с this

Comment: @KoVadim именно

Comment: видимо  нужно как-то через lParam: EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProcMy, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this));

Comment: @Xie  - это можно сделать, если функция будет статической. А иначе, у Вас будет не совпадать сигнатура. Все  не статические функции члены класса имеют неявный первый параметр this.

Comment: @Xie, нужно наверное в вопросе внести ясность, предоставив больше информации о том, что вы хотите сделать